# Синхронизация движущихся объектов Unity

Tags: unity3d

Извечная проблема синхронизации. Столкнулся с проблемой синхронизации, перечитал кучу материала, но явно нужно ещё больше по данному вопросу. Проблема заключается в следующем:
Я придерживаюсь авторитарной архитектуры клиент-серверного взаимодействия. Игрок нажав кнопку ехать вперед, отправляет команду на сервер, сервер передвигает машину и отравляет координаты её текущего положения, после чего через функцию линейной интерполяции Lerp, я передвигаю объект в новое место, но судя по всему, между приходом следующего сигнала и достижения конечной точки движения машины, проходит слишком много времени, в результате чего наблюдаются рывки, попытки изменять третий параметр Lerp замедляют движения машины, но полностью не исключают рывки.

Мне кажется, что нужно использовать экстраполяцию, то есть двигаться в заданном направлении, пока не придет следующее сообщение с новой точкой. Как лучше реализовать данный механизм? 
У меня недостаточно знаний по Unity, ведь мы должны двигать объект в цикле, пока цикл не получит сообщение о новой координате. Но для реализации этой схемы нужно знать метод прослушки канала, чтобы прервать цикл, когда придет новое сообщение.

И получится что-то типа такого:

```
moveCar(Vector3 newPosition, float delta)
{
   Vector3 direction = new Vector3(transform.position - newPosition)
   transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, Time.deltaTime * delta);

while(не пришел сигнал)
    {
       transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, transform.position+direction,Time.deltaTime * delta);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не помню точно как называется подход, но можно реализовать что-то такое:

1. Обрабатывается инпут. Данные идут на клинткую логику и сервер.
2. Клиент сохраняет своё предыдущее состояние и начинает движение в сторону, куда указал инпут.
3. В идеале, параллельно с 2м пунктом сетевой модуль отправляет на сервер данные.
4. От сервера приходит ответ. В случае, если сервер дал разрешение не делаем ничего. Если сервер ответил отказом - возвращаем клиент в предыдущее состояние.
5. Время от времени шлём полный стейт от сервера для синхронизации.

Но, в частности, для гонок такой подход может не подойти, ибо все запросы должны выполнятся строго последовательно, смена порядка сломает состояние. Да и синхронизация стейта может привести к "подергиванию", ибо в гоночках все считается в числах с плавающей точкой и из-за этого может произойти утечка точности.

Comment: Я так и сделал. По факту по сети передаются только 4 параметра газ, тормоз, лева или право. Так же, для проверки отправляю координаты серверу о своем положении, если оно сильно разнится, то отправляю запрос на синхронизацию. 
Но все равно, если начать игру тестировать в реальной сети, из-за того, что пинг не является константой, то достаточно быстро набегает погрешность и дистанция между объектами приходится синхронизировать. 
И как с этим бороться, пока не понятно

Comment: а какой сетевой протокол используете для работы?

Comment: и TCP и UDP. Кажется я разобрался, нужно получить среднею задержку отправки запроса серверу от клиента. Далее, когда клиент совершает какое то действие, он отправляет запрос, ждет среднее время задержки и, не дожидаясь ответа от сервера, начинает выполнять движение.

Comment: Ну да, идея была такова:) Главное помнить, что сервер может ответить отказом за запрос клиента, даже, если клиент это действие совершил